# How to do you make a ListBox display all files in a drive?

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding an Anti-Virus at the moment, so it's been very complicated to code it and design it. Anyway, the other day I ran into a problem, where my ListBox is not displaying all the files that are in the selected drive/directory.

I'll put some code and images so you get the idea.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox3.Items.Clear()
    FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory) & "Boot\"
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each strDir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        For Each strFile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDir)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(strFile)
            ListBox3.Items.Add(strFile)
        Next
    Next
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

However, instead of the files appearing in the ListBox (ListBox3), it just gives a black screen. Maybe I should remove the TabControl that it is surrounded by?

[See how it's black? It even happens when I run it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjqZZ.png)

Hope this helps! Comment if you need more information.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` What is that doing there? Maybe you should remove that so you can actually see what the problems are.

Comment: so you just want to be able to get all the files on the c drive and have them listed in a listbox? so im guessing you are having trouble doing that due to security reasons?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want to simplify your events by creating subs and standardizing the code instead of embedding it directly into the button click. I have created a working example of how to load directories and files dynamically.

I would also recommend doing a isolated experiment, you can easily throw together a test project to isolate the directories in question and the layout you are trying to achieve. It could be that there are other events causing noise in your debugging.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        load_dirs(ListBox2, "H:\")
    End Sub
    Sub load_files(LB As ListBox,
                   IO_dir As String)
        Dim Files_ = IO.Directory.GetFiles(IO_dir)
        With LB.Items
            .Clear()
            .AddRange(Files_)
        End With
    End Sub
    Sub load_dirs(LB As ListBox,
               IO_dir As String)
        Dim dir_ = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(IO_dir)
        With LB.Items
            .Clear()
            .AddRange(dir_)
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            Dim lb As ListBox = sender
            load_files(ListBox1, lb.SelectedItem)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Darnit, it's still black for some reason. Maybe it's an error I've done when I made the Form? @Teach Me How To Spell

Comment: Yep is was an error I did with making it, fixed now :) But your code works great! Thanks man :)

Comment: The empty `Catch` block is an anti-pattern. Remove it. Also, although this refactoring is arguably an improvement, it's unclear how this solves the asker's problem of a black listbox.

Comment: whenever interacting with controls and index changes there chance the application will throw errors. This is my style when using controls do not micro manage my code I was simply sharing how I would solve the problem.

Comment: Also CODY where is your answer instead you are just focusing on taking down my code but you are not even trying to help the person with the  question.